# How to stop featured image thumbnail [set as background image] on blog index page just repeating same image across all posts

Tags: php, css, post-thumbnails, blog-page

How to stop featured image thumbnail [set as background image] on blog index page just repeating same image across all posts:

i have this code here:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'set_featured_background', 99);
function set_featured_background() {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
        ?>
        <style>
        .has-post-thumbnail {
            background-image: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>');
            background-size: 100% 100%; 
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

And ive tried a few different variations but it always jsut finds the most recent posts image and uses that across all posts. Do i need to be trying to put in a check to make sure it does the same thing every unique post. For example: If this post has a unique ID find its thumbnail image and apply as a style. Or is it because im trying to add it to the css class has-post-thumbnail which is applied to all posts? [that have a thumbnail]

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it because im trying to add it to the css class `.has-post-thumbnail` which is applied to all posts?

Yes, `set_featured_background()` gets first post from the loop and add `.has-post-thumbnail` to styles. All posts that have thumbnail (with class `.has-post-thumbnail`) will have the same background.

Try setting the background in the template file responsible for displaying posts on the home page, probably in `content.php` or `front-page.php`.

```
<?php
    $attr_style= '';
    if ( is_home() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        $attr_style = ' style="background: url('. $url.'); background-size: 100% 100%;" ';
    }
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); echo $attr_style; ?>>
```

Comment: even if i take set_featured_background() out, it still repeats. Issue is im trying to do it without basically writing a whole new blog loop, but from what i can tell it looks like im going to have to do that so i can inline style this one bit.

Comment: Is the site preview somewhere available? @Moose

Comment: yeah - http://www.visualiseitinprogress.co.uk/WhifflerCarCentre/wordpress/extras/blog/

Comment: if you inspect the img inside the entrycontent, and untick display none, you will see what its supposed to look like

Comment: Why is `display: none` set there, if you want the image to be visible? Do you want to remove [this](http://www.visualiseitinprogress.co.uk/WhifflerCarCentre/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/blog-feature-large-1.png) from background? @Moose

Comment: because if those images are infact background images i can make it responsive... its much harder to do that with static images loaded into the post itself, which is why im trying to take that image and have it loaded as a background image! Ive been told to keep the design intact as much as possible but with static images it breaks instantly.

Comment: you can't set background in `.has-post-thumbnail` how you do it now, because it affects all posts with thumbnail. Comment out `add_action( 'wp_head', 'set_featured_background', 99);`. Try changing the template file displaying the post (add style to line with `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" ...`).  @Moose

Comment: i know, im trying to find a way to do this without inline style, but it seems like thats not gonna happen

Comment: It can definitely be done and it's not that complex - you're just tackling it from the wrong direction. nmr's answer is correct, if you're applying a style on a per post basis then you're going to, at the very least, have to inline-style the `background-image`, the rest you can just manage with your standard css file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the ID of the post (which should be part of the id or class of the article-tag) as additional selector for the style:

```
<style>
    #post-<?php the_ID();?>.has-post-thumbnail {
        background-image: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>');
        background-size: 100% 100%; 
    }
</style>
```